# How to get buttons to overlap the image in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene1, scene2;

    Button button1, button2;
    ImageView iv = new ImageView();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        window = primaryStage;
        Label label1 = new Label("First stage");
        Button button1 = new Button("PLAY");

        //Layout 1
        VBox layout1 = new VBox(20);
        scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 1280, 720);
        layout1.getChildren().add(changeBackground("file:menuBackground.png"));
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);

        //defines dimensions of vbox so button and label can be centered
        layout1.prefWidthProperty().bind(window.widthProperty());
        layout1.prefHeightProperty().bind(window.heightProperty());

        layout1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        button1.setOnAction(event -> window.setScene(scene2));

        //Button 2
        Button button2 = new Button("This scene sucks, go back to scene 1");
        button2.setOnAction(event -> window.setScene(scene1));

        //Layout 2
        StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
        layout2.getChildren().add(button2);
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 1280, 720);
        layout2.getChildren().add(changeBackground("file:gameBackground.png"));

        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.setTitle("Scramblo");
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Node changeBackground(String imageFile){
        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
        Image image = new Image(imageFile);
        iv.setImage(image);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getWidth();
        iv.setFitHeight(height);
        iv.setFitHeight(width);
        iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
        return iv;
    }
}
```

So what I want is for the buttons to overlap the background images. I want to see the buttons and be able to interact with them with just having the background chillin' there. Right now when I add the background it completely removes the buttons/labels and anything else I put on there. I'm confused on how to go about this! Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could post a link to the image so that I can try running your code on my computer? By the way, you can use class [Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) rather than `java.awt.Toolkit`

Comment: @Abra https://gyazo.com/6ef9e0d7537351f209c3fcff12a5a884

Comment: whatever you do, __do not mix__ awt/swing and javafx - except when you know _exactly_ what you are doing. And then import the single classes you need (vs. the wildcard import)

Answer (score 0):

Make `layout1` a `StackPane` and not a `VBox`. Use a `VBox` as the container for `label1` and `button1` and add the `VBox` to `layout1`.

A `StackPane` places nodes added to it one on top of the other. The first node added is the lowest. Hence you want to first add the background image to the `StackPane` and then the button. That way the button appears on top of the image.

Similarly for `layout2`, because you first added `button2` and after that added the image, the image sits on top of the button and therefore hides the button. You just need to swap them, i.e. add the image first and then add the button.

Note that the URL for the image, in your code, looks incorrect to me. I simply put the image in the same folder as the compiled `Main.class` file and used method `getResource()` to get the image file.

Also, I don't think it is a good idea to mix AWT and JavaFX. JavaFX has class [Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) that will provide you with the screen dimensions.

Here is your code with my fixes. Compare it with your code to see the differences.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene1, scene2;
    Button button1, button2;
    ImageView iv = new ImageView();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D screenBounds =  screen.getBounds();
        primaryStage.setWidth(screenBounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(screenBounds.getHeight());
        window = primaryStage;

        Label label1 = new Label("First stage");
        Button button1 = new Button("PLAY");
        VBox vBox = new VBox(20);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Layout 1
        StackPane layout1 = new StackPane();
        scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 1280, 720);
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(changeBackground("snowymountains.png"), vBox);

        // defines dimensions of vbox so button and label can be centered
        layout1.prefWidthProperty().bind(window.widthProperty());
        layout1.prefHeightProperty().bind(window.heightProperty());

        layout1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        button1.setOnAction(event -> window.setScene(scene2));

        // Button 2
        Button button2 = new Button("This scene sucks, go back to scene 1");
        button2.setOnAction(event -> window.setScene(scene1));

        // Layout 2
        StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 1280, 720);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(changeBackground("gameBackground.jpg"), button2);

        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.setTitle("Scramblo");
        window.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Node changeBackground(String imageFile) {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(imageFile);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
        Image image = new Image(url.toExternalForm());
        iv.setImage(image);
        iv.setFitHeight(window.getHeight());
        iv.setFitHeight(window.getWidth());
        iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
        return iv;
    }
}
```